# Return value based on column comparison

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, excel-formula, index-match

I have the following dataframe

| value | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 7.0 | 8.0 |
| 2.0 | 9.0 | 8.8 |
| 3.0 | 9.5 | 9.1 |
| 4.0 | 10.0 | 9.4 |
| 5.0 | 13.0 | 9.7 |
| 6.0 | 15.0 | 9.9 |
| 7.0 | 16.0 | 10.6 |
| 9.0 | 17.0 | 17.0 |

What I'm attempting to do:

example:

I'm thinking some sort of if/else statetement:

```
    -if 
        A < B
    return 1.0 ==> when A=7.0 < B=8.0
    - if A=B
    return 9.0 ==> when A=17 == B=17
    -else: 
        if A > B
         look at the two smaller values from B column that match the target value A and return the value of that value at index+1.
         Let's say the value A=9.0 so in this example I'm going to look at 8.0 and 8.8, but I'm going to return the next value B=9.1 which is 3.0.
```

Couple more examples in case it's unclear:

if A=9, check B=8.0 and B=8.8 and return 3.0

if A=9.5, check B=9.1 and B=9.4 and return 5.0

if A=10.0, check B=9.7 and B=9.9 and return 7.0

if A=16, check B=9.9 and B=10.6 and return 9.0

I tried using numpy for this, and indexing it... np.where looked promising but I keep getting stuck in the second part. Can anyone help? All the values are sorted in the ascending order.

Excel formula, I'm not sure if this is helpful at all but I'll add it here anyway:

IF(A<B,value, INDEX(value, match(A,B,1)+1))

Working code:

```
import pandas as pd
A=7.0
# A=9.0
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "value": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6], 
               'A': [7., 9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.],
               'B': [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 8.4, 8.5]
             })
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if A < df['B'][i]:
        #this should print 1.0 if A=7.0
        print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        for j in range(i, df.shape[0]):
            if A < df['B'][j]:
                # a little lost here but if A=9.0, it should print 3.0
                print(df["value"][j])
```

Comment: if you have dataframe then maybe use its functions for this instead of numpy.

Comment: maybe better show code which you created. And show expected result for your example data.

Comment: I just updated the description to include the code

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem to use `if`/`else` to print `1.0` when `A == 7.0` (or maybe rather `df['A'] == 7.0`

Comment: The first if statement is easy... is the else statement that's problematic... I couldn't make df["A"] work in the else section when A>B...

Comment: I don't understand your if/else descrition. Better show expected result (as another column in df)

Comment: your code almost works for me when I put correct values in `DataFrame` - your DataFrame has different values then your table at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code almost work for me - the biggest problem is that in code DataFrame has different values then table at the top - so it gives different results and it doesn't match to expected results.

And it needs

- `df['A'][i]` instead of `A`
- `break` in second `for`-loop to exist loop when it finds first matching element
- `<=` in first `if` to run for `<` and `==`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,   6,   7.,   9.], 
    "A":     [7.,  9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.,  16.,  17.],
    "B":     [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 9.7, 9.9, 10.6, 17.0]
})

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] <= df['B'][i]:  # both `<` and `==`
        #print(df["value"][i])
        print(f'{df["A"][i]:5.1f} <= {df["B"][i]:5.1f}          ==> {df["value"][i]:5.1f}')
    else:
        for j in range(i+1, df.shape[0]):
            if df['A'][i] < df['B'][j]:
                #print(df["value"][j])
                print(f'{df["A"][i]:5.1f}  > {df["B"][i]:5.1f} (<{df["B"][j]:5.1f}) ==> {df["value"][j]:5.1f}')
                break
```

Result:

```
  7.0 <=   8.0          ==>   1.0
  9.0  >   8.8 (<  9.1) ==>   3.0
  9.5  >   9.1 (<  9.7) ==>   5.0
 10.0  >   9.4 (< 10.6) ==>   7.0
 13.0  >   9.7 (< 17.0) ==>   9.0
 15.0  >   9.9 (< 17.0) ==>   9.0
 16.0  >  10.6 (< 17.0) ==>   9.0
 17.0 <=  17.0          ==>   9.0
```

---

To make it more readable you could use `df.iterrows()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,   6,   7.,   9.], 
    "A":     [7.,  9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.,  16.,  17.],
    "B":     [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 9.7, 9.9, 10.6, 17.0]
})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] <= row['B']:  # both `<` and `==`
        #print(row["value"])
        print(f'{row["A"]:5.1f} <= {row["B"]:5.1f}          ==> {row["value"]:5.1f}')
    else:
        for other_index, other_row in df[index+1:].iterrows():
            if row['A'] < other_row['B']:
                #print(df["value"][j])
                print(f'{row["A"]:5.1f}  > {row["B"]:5.1f} (<{other_row["B"]:5.1f}) ==> {other_row["value"]:5.1f}')
                break
```